# Error: "MyPlugin" is not a valid value for --theme

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x, cakephp-bake

Even though my plugin seems to be loaded, baking doesn't seem to be able to find it.

Command used:

```
root@f2bdce131cdd:/var/www/html/MyApp# bin/cake bake model test_bake_commands -t MyPlugin
Error: "MyPlugin" is not a valid value for --theme. Please use one of "Bake, Migrations"
```

It seems to be loaded too:

```
root@f2bdce131cdd:/var/www/html/MyApp# bin/cake plugin loaded
AuditStash
Bake
Cake/TwigView
DebugKit
Migrations
Muffin/Footprint
MyPlugin
```

Comment: Plugins will only be recognized as bake themes in case they have a readable (`is_dir()`) `templates/bake` folder.

Comment: @ndm does case matter? I have it as Bake (capital "B"). Interesting. We shifted to a Linux environment from Windows where it worked.

Comment: @ndm I changed the case and it worked!

Comment: Linux FS is usually case sensitive by default, while Windows isn't, so yes, it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: renamed `MyPlugin/templates/Bake` to `MyPlugin/templates/bake`.